# Should I edit my Answer to this question?

Tags: discussion, editing, answers

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128855/how-to-save-screenshots-as-jpg-automatically/128865#128865).

Today I noticed the question has been edited and now my answer only makes partial sense.
Should I edit it accordingly?

Secondly, if it was a decision by a moderator to edit this question, why did they not send me a comment to suggest that I modify the answer to make it more meaningful. Also some comments left by others are now redundant because the question has been edited.  I guess I'm using this as an example of what to do in this situation.  I don't want to leave a legacy of ambiguity for other members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good spot - and perhaps an unfortunate oversight from the editor.

The edit was clear and was valid - the title and main part of the question was referring to gnome-screenshot.  The reference to Paint wasnt key to the question.

Can I suggest, when reviewing and answering questions - best prompt the OP by dropping a comment to split the question into multiple questions.

If you can, edit the question to focus on the OP's main area and remove the non-associated part of the question.

Finally - to answer your meta question directly - yes, if you can, edit your answer to reflect the edited question - or delete it if you are unsure.

Thanks.